# Prediction error of a decision tree

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, decision-tree, supervised-learning

I'm using decision-tree-learner [algorithm](https://github.com/9ettore6/ProgettoAI/blob/master/project/Learning.py) to build my decision tree and to test it on a dataset.

I'm trying also to calculate the prediction error rate of my tree, so I can plot a graph with learning curves of my test and training set. I do a loop where my algorithm is applicated n-times (n arbitrary). My variable internal_nodes store the number of internal node generated (this will be my abscissa in the learning curve graph) and I returned it at every call.

I create count_error() to measure the difference between predicted and desired value.

```
def count_errors(examples, target, tree):
    counter = 0
    for ex in examples: # examples is a list that contains list of example
        desired = ex[target]
        predicted = tree(ex) # use __call__(self,example) to obtain leaf value
        if desired != predicted:
            counter += 1
    return float(counter / len(examples)) * float(100)`

def __call__(self, example):
    """Given an example, classify it using the attribute and the branches."""
    attrvalue = example[self.attr] #attr is a list of integers that index into an example
    return self.branches[attrvalue](example)
```

The errors that occur are always 0. I've tested my algorithm with one iteration and seems that it works. I think that the mistake is inside how i calculate errors.
The complete repository is on my [github](https://github.com/9ettore6/ProgettoAI/tree/master/project).

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have integer division when you’re calculating the error ratio. Try this:

```
return float(counter) / len(examples) * float(100)
```